# Is repr enough to prevent shell injection in Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Say I have the following code:

```py
os.system(f'echo {repr(input())}')
```

`repr` outputs the string in syntactically correct python. i.e. `repr("hello there ${ls -l}") == "'hello there ${ls -l}'"`. It outputs the string with single quotes, which in bash do not allow substitution. Therefore, theoretically it prevents any kind of shell injection on bash and POSIX shell. Is that the case?

Comment: This is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/340688). Why would you ever want to send user input to `os.system`, just to call `echo`? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @zvone The question is not about "how to escape shell input in python" but rather "does repr escape shell injection correctly?". I asked this with the purpose of learning. This is not my actual use case and I usually do use subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question because I realized this is not safe. I mentioned in my question that `repr` outputs the string with single quotes. This is not always the case. When the string contains a single quote character, `repr` wraps it in double quotes, which allows substitution. The following input therefore executes the ls -l command:

```
' $(ls -l)
```

The correct tool to use for shell quoting is [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), not `repr`. You can also use functions like [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `os.system` and pass the command as a list instead of a single string, to entirely avoid the need for quoting.

Comment: The correct way is **not** to use `os.system`. As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) says, [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module is preferred.